# repeat items in asp.net vb with json.net

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net

I have a problem with the following situation.

json:

```
    {
  "reviews": [
    {
      "title": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
      "user": {
        "firstName": "Tom",
        "hasPicture": false,
        "gender": "MALE",
        "ageGroup": "71",
        "registerDate": 1337040000000
      },
      "bookingDate": 1459468800000,
      "product": {
        "name": "XS33"
      },
      "recommendation": true,
      "proofedBooking": true
    },
    {
      "title": "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
      "user": {
        "firstName": "Jim",
        "hasPicture": false,
        "gender": "MALE",
        "ageGroup": "31",
        "registerDate": 1337040000000
      },
      "bookingDate": 1459468800000,
      "product": {
        "name": "XS33"
      },
      "recommendation": true,
      "proofedBooking": true
    },
    {
      "title": "ccccccccccccccccccccccccc",
      "user": {
        "firstName": "Jane",
        "hasPicture": false,
        "gender": "FEMALE",
        "ageGroup": "68",
        "registerDate": 1337040000000
      },
      "bookingDate": 1459468800000,
      "product": {
        "name": "XS33"
      },
      "recommendation": true,
      "proofedBooking": true
    }


  ],
  "total": 4396,
  "facets": {

  }
}
```

How can I do a repeater and display the results like:

start repeater of title

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

ccccccccccccccccccccccc

end repeater

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: json is loaded from local file

Comment: Deserialize the JSON into objects, and feed those to your Repeater.